# VFP9 app different date format on different servers

Tags: date, visual-foxpro

I have the same executable for a VFP9 app running on 2 servers.
On server 1 when user enters date 10/01/2022 into a text field with format property set to KD, and when text field loses focus, the value in the text field gets changed to 10/1/2022.
On server 2 when user enters date 10/01/2022 into a text field with format property set to KD, and when text field loses focus, the value in the text field does not get changed so it remains 10/01/2022.

I believe the format property having the D means to use windows settings and from what I have read/googled, perhaps the windows short date may be different on the 2 servers. Not really sure about any of that. Also, I can't find any VFP or otherwise documentation that would tell me from inside my VFP app, the windows setting for "is short date on?".

Any help appreciated,
John

Comment: As you said: quoted from the Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP2  <kbd>F1</kbd> Help file:
`Format Property`: "D" _Uses the current SET DATE format._

See also https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pk5h.htm

Comment: Stefan, Thank You for the response but I am afraid I do not understand what you are telling me. I am aware that the "D" in the format property causes VFP to apply the current SET DATE format. What I do not know is how do I get VFP to tell me what that current SET DATE format is, as it would have to be different on the 2 servers, AND, the answer is NOT ?set("DATE") because that does not tell me the WINDOWS setting for "short date". Hope that makes sense, John

Comment: You wrote _"Not really sure about any of that"_, so I thought you are having no local F1 Help installed. What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> tell me from inside my VFP app, the windows setting for "is short date on?"

I'd put it like: a local VFP instance's Date display is not affected by O/S setting as long as your code does not `Set SysFormats On`. The following custom check works for me in an En/US Windows as well as a German, and a French Windows UI. What are yours?

```
SET DATE SHORT
? ISALPHA(DTOC(DATE())) && returns .F.
SET DATE LONG
? ISALPHA(DTOC(DATE())) && returns .T.
```

As for the comment:

> Perhaps this is a simpler asking of my question: The same exact executable is running on 2 servers. lddate=ctod("09/20/2022") On server 1, ?dtoc(lddate) returns "09/20/2022" On server 2 ?dtoc(lddate) returns "9/20/2022". What is causing the different results

Nobody can tell without seeing the two server's regional settings and the `foxpro` code of your executable.
Try to remove or disable any

```
Set Sysformats On
```

line in the `foxpro` code, the default settings there ought to be as documented
https://www.vfphelp.com/help/_5wn12pf0l.htm

> The default date setting is AMERICAN

i.e. `dtoc(Date(2022,9,20)) should return "09/20/2022"` on both servers

Another possible cause could be a combination of an unusual Windows Short Date format. e.g. like  `d/M/yyyy`, together with doing a `SET DATE SHORT` in the `foxpro` code

Comment: Perhaps this is a simpler asking of my question: The same exact executable is running on 2 servers. lddate=ctod("09/20/2022") On server 1, ?dtoc(lddate) returns "09/20/2022" On server 2 ?dtoc(lddate) returns "9/20/2022". What is causing the different results?

Comment: SYSFORMATS is NOT ON. I looked at the windows regional settings on both servers. There are identical, yet I am getting differing results on the 2 servers. It does not appear I am going to find the reason this is occurring. This problem arose about 2 weeks ago. What changed 2 weeks ago? I was working on a different issue. I noticed my app running on any cloud server (they are RemoteApp running over RDP on cloud servers) were not playing any sounds. While debugging this sound issue, .........

Comment: ........I went to File-->Options on server2 and tried toggeling the "Play Warning Sounds" off and on. I ended up NOT making any change but somehow saving those options changed something to do with date and time (again NOTHING was changed). That is when this issue with dates arose. While trying to find this date issue I came across some VFP Help that says if you are doing lcMonth=left(lcdate,2) that is bad practice because if for whatever unknown reason lcdate contains "9/30/2022" rather than "09/30/2022", it's crash city.........

Comment: ........It appears I will have to go thru my app and ensure I always fix lcdate before parsing.

Comment: Okay, another possible cause could be a combination of an unusual Windows Short Date format. e.g. like `d/M/yyyy`, together with doing a `SET DATE SHORT` in the `foxpro` code